# Escape key not closng the Dialog

Tags: mfc, dialog

I have seen so many posts about how to prevent the escape key from closing a CDIalog but in my case I want to close the dialog but it doesn`t.

I have created a sample MFC Dialog application thats adds property sheet and 2 property pages. I tried putting pretranslatemessage, OnCancel, KillFocus overrides into the property pages and the dialog but that doesn't get hit. 
Used following code:

```
#include "proppage1.h"
#include "proppage2.h"
#include "mySheet.h"

// ......
protected:
       // proppage1,proppage2 are the class dervied from CPropertyPage
       proppage1 pg1;
       proppage2 pg2;

       // mySheet is the class dervied from CPropertySheet
       mySheet *m_sheet;
```

In CMFCDlg::OnInitDialog() of MFCDlg.CPP

```
       m_sheet = new mySheet(L"mySheet",this,0);
       m_sheet->AddPage(&pg1);
       m_sheet->AddPage(&pg2);

       m_sheet->Create(this, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE  , 0);
       m_sheet->ModifyStyleEx (0, WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT);
       m_sheet->ModifyStyle( 0, WS_TABSTOP );
```

I dont get any events fired in propertypages and dialog.
If I place some controls on the property pages, then events are fired and can be catched in property pages.
However,in other case why wouldn't the Esc and other event get fired?

Please suggest?

Thanks,
Nikhil

Comment: I think it may be a focus issue? The CDialog has a propertysheet with 2 pages on it. Could one of them be stealing the focus from the main dialog and preventing this? But I'm not sure if it's a focus issue because one of the thing I did that just added control on property page when control has a focus the event get fired.

Answer (score 1):

```
 m_sheet = new mySheet(L"mySheet",this,0);
 m_sheet->AddPage(&pg1);
 m_sheet->AddPage(&pg2);
```

I believe both `pg1` and `pg2` are objects of type `CPropertyPage` or derived class. If they are `CDialog` or derived objects, it may not work - ensure the message-map is correctly mapped with `CPropertyPage` and not `CDialog`

Further, there is no need to call `Create` for a `CPropertySheet` object. Constructor does the thing. Where are you calling `DoModal` or `ShowWindow`? If you are calling `CPropertySheet::DoModal`, there is no need to allocate property-sheet on heap.

I would have simply used:

```
CPropertySheet sheet( _T("MySheet Title") );
CPropertyPage page1(ID1), page2(ID2);
sheet.AddPage(&page1);
sheet.AddPage(&page2);

sheet.DoModal();
```

Comment: I was using m_pdlgPropSheet->SetWindowPos() which takes care of showing the propertysheet.I do not want to use DoModal since I want to make this as Modeless. I found the code which was preventin from getting the events,It was m_sheet->ModifyStyleEx (0, WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT) which sets the property sheet as parent.If I remove this line ESCAPE works fine and it closes the dialog. Not sure what will be the impact if I dont set to WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT.

Answer (score 0):

In your property sheet, you can capture the WM_KEYDOWN message and check for escape

```
BOOL CInfoPropertySheet::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    switch(pMsg->message)
    {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            if( pMsg->wParam == VK_ESCAPE )
```